# dask, how to cancel computation?

Tags: python, task, dask

1) How to cancel dataframe apply? e.g

```
dask_df.apply(myfunc)  # Long running
```

2) In general, how to stop all running tasks?
There is `client.cancel(futures)`.  But I don't have a reference to the futures. Does dask store a list of them?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not provide a way to interrupt a running thread, so this limits what Dask can do.

If you are using the distributed scheduler, you can indeed use the futures interface to check on the state of calculations and issue cancel commands. For instance, instead of calling the `compute` method on the Dask object, you can use the `client`'s version

```
fut = client.compute(dataframe_thing)
```

This produces a future, and works asynchronously (i.e., returns immediately instead of blocking until done). You can cancel this future (or delete it, so Dask considers it no longer needed). However, that will only stop the contained tasks from being scheduled - those that are are already running will continue doing so.